# Usage of colon in jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

I've seen code that shows jQuery selector like this: $(":text"), what's the difference between this and the CSS Selector? I know some people would say the CSS Selector is faster, but why then this selector is done?

In the code I've seen, the writer used the jQuery extension everywhere, is that a right practice? When do we really need to use the jQuery extension selectors, and is there any documentation for it, because I've seen the writer using $(":selected"), to get the selected item in a dropdown list. Is there a documentation for it on what we can select using this way?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate. Also, [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the keyword is pseudo selector. Some docs are here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/